# How do I order my key from best to worst?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have created a bar plot with each variable having up to four data points. I have managed to plot it successfully. The only issue I'm currently experiencing is the key is not in the order I would like it to be. I would ideally want the key ranging from best to worst or in this case 'Excellent' to 'Not so good'.

What part of code would I need to change for the order to go from best to worst?

```
df <- read.csv("//ecfle35/STAFF-HOME$/MaxEmery/open event feedback/October/Q3.csv")

df %>%

  #First the dataset needs to be long not wide

  gather(review,

         count,

         Excellent:Not.so.good,

         factor_key = T) %>%

  #Lets get ride of N/A

  filter(count != 'N/A') %>%

  #convert count from string to number

  #Remove the annoying full stop in the middle of text

  mutate(count = as.integer(count),

         review = gsub('\\.', ' ', review)) %>%

  ggplot(aes(

    x = Faculty,

    y = count,

    fill = review

  )) +

  geom_bar(position = 'dodge',

           stat = 'identity') +

  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 22, by = 2)) +

  labs(title = 'Teaching Staff Ratings',

       x = 'Faculty',

       y = 'Count') +

  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Below is an image of how it currently looks -

[Graphic of my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZpHI.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you convert to a factor without specifying the levels, the levels get decided based on the alphabetical order. Add a `mutate()` in the pipe to relevel the `review` column before sending it to `ggplot()`.